# Retrieving pixel data not working correctly with UIGraphicsImageRenderer image

Tags: swift, uigraphicsrenderer

I have the following code to get the pixel data from a `UIImage`, this works for most images however does not work when I create an image using the `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`. I was hoping someone knew a solution to this.

My current code generates a simple image but then accessing the data gives unexpected results.

```
func myDraw() {

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
    let image = renderer.image { context in

        context.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context.cgContext.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        context.cgContext.fillPath()

        context.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.cgContext.addRect(CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        context.cgContext.fillPath()

    }

    let providerData = image.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
    let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(providerData)!
    var pixels = [PixelData]()
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: 160000-1, by: 4) {
        pixels.append(PixelData(a:data[i+3], r:data[i+0], g:data[i+1], b:data[i+2]))
    }
    self.canvas.image = self.imageFromARGB32Bitmap(pixels: pixels, width: 200, height: 200)

}
```

I have used the following code to generate the image to see if it was working correctly.

```
func imageFromARGB32Bitmap(pixels: [PixelData], width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage? {
    guard width > 0 && height > 0 else { return nil }
    guard pixels.count == width * height else { return nil }

    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitsPerPixel = 32

    var data = pixels // Copy to mutable []
    guard let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: NSData(bytes: &data,
                                                        length: data.count * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size)
        )
        else { return nil }

    guard let cgim = CGImage(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
        bytesPerRow: width * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size,
        space: rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
        provider: providerRef,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: true,
        intent: .defaultIntent
        )
        else { return nil }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgim)
}
```

Comment: A super minor, unrelated point, but your `stride(from: 0, to: 160000-1, by: 4)` seems to imply that you think that `stride` will stride up through that final value. But it doesn’t. It stops before it gets there, unlike `stride(from:through:by:)`. You can lose that `-1` in your `stride` call.

Comment: @OscarApeland The `pngData` is definitely not what he wants. That takes him a step further from where he wants to get. He needs the image if he’s then going to retrieve the uncompressed provider data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations:

1. Your code assumes that `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` generates images with scale of 1, whereas it defaults to 0 (i.e. whatever scale your device uses).

   Instead, force the scale to 1:

   ```
   let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
   format.scale = 1
   let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), format: format)
   ```
2. It’s not the issue here, but we must note that your code just assumes that the format of `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat` will be a particular byte order and format, as does your `imageFromARGB32Bitmap`. If you look at Apple [Technical Note 1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1509/_index.html) (from which your code was undoubtedly originally adapted), they don’t just assume that the buffer will be in a particular format. When we want to manipulate/examine a buffer, we should (a) create a context of the desired format, (b) draw our image (or whatever) to that context, and only then can we  reliably look at the provider data.
3. The `imageFromARGB32Bitmap` works, but it makes me a bit nervous.

   - The use of `MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size`: [Apple advises](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2432227-size) :

     > When allocating memory for multiple instances of T using an unsafe pointer, use a multiple of the type’s `stride` instead of its `size`.

     So, I’d use `stride`.
   - What if `stride` wasn’t 4 like you expect it to be? I can’t imagine it would ever not be 4, but with the data provider assumes that they will be packed in. It’s a minor observation, but I might make this assumption explicit.
   - Are we 100% assured that dereferencing `&data` will give us a contiguous buffer? I’d lean towards [`withContiguousStorageIfAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126963-withcontiguousstorageifavailable) just to be safe.

   For example:

   ```
   func imageFromARGB32Bitmap(pixels: [PixelData], width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage? {
       guard width > 0,
           height > 0,
           pixels.count == width * height else { return nil }

       let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
       let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
       let bitsPerComponent = 8
       let bitsPerPixel = 32

       let stride = MemoryLayout<PixelData>.stride
       assert(stride == 4)

       return pixels.withContiguousStorageIfAvailable { bufferPointer -> UIImage? in
           let data = Data(buffer: bufferPointer)

           return CGDataProvider(data: data as CFData)
               .flatMap { CGImage(width: width,
                                  height: height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                  bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
                                  bytesPerRow: width * stride,
                                  space: rgbColorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                                  provider: $0,
                                  decode: nil,
                                  shouldInterpolate: true,
                                  intent: .defaultIntent) }
               .flatMap { UIImage(cgImage: $0) }
           } ?? nil
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use `render.pngData` instead `render.image`, then get image from `UIImage.init(data: pngData)`

I met the same problem when I wanted to get pixel color from `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` generated image.

the code:

```
  let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: .init(width: 414, height: 100))
  // iPhone Xs, so scale is 3, the img actual size is 1242x300
  let img = render.image { ctx in
      ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
      ctx.cgContext.addRect(.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
      ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
  }
```

print img pixel color information:

```
 let pixelData = img.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
 let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
 let width = img.cgImage!.width
 let height = img.cgImage!.height

 for y in 0..<height {
     for x in 0..<width {
         let pixelInfo = (width * y + x) * 4

         print("xy: \(x) \(y) rgba: \(data[pixelInfo]) \(data[pixelInfo + 1]) \(data[pixelInfo + 2]) \(data[pixelInfo + 3])")
     }
 }
```

the print result:

```
 xy: 0 0 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 xy: 1 0 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 xy: 2 0 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 xy: 3 0 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 xy: 4 0 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 ...
 xy: 1240 0 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 xy: 1241 0 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 xy: 0 1 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 ...
 xy: 5 1 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 xy: 6 1 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 xy: 7 1 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 xy: 8 1 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 ...
 xy: 1240 1 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 xy: 1241 1 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 xy: 0 2 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 xy: 1 2 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 ...     
 xy: 11 2 rgba: 0 0 0 0
 xy: 12 2 rgba: 255 0 0 255
 ...
```

I found that there is some offsets from second row, and when I changed img width 414 to 400, the offsets were gone.

I don't know the reason, and if someone knew, please add a comment below my answer.